# Spring RestController with java validation API. Too verbose error messages

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, dto

I have to write a Rest Controller using Spring.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/mycontroller", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public MyDTOOuptup myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO input) {

        ... body ...
    }
```

I wrote a DTO input object that it represents the Request Body of my controller.
Into the DTO I added some validation rules to validate the input before to analize the request into the controller.

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class MyDTO {

        @NotNull(message="my custom error message for field_a")
        @JsonProperty("field_A")
        private String fieldA;

        @NotNull(message="my custom error message for field_b")
        @JsonProperty("field_B")
        private String fieldB;

    }
```

It works fine. In case of wrong input I receive 400 - Bad request and appropriate errors description into the response body.

But, I saw that this json body is too verbose.

```
    {
    "timestamp": "2020-03-31T14:29:42.401+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.myDTO.field_a",
                "NotNull.field_a",
                "NotNull.java.lang.String",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "myDTO.field_a",
                        "field_a"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "field_a",
                    "code": "field_a"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "my custom error message for field_a",
            "objectName": "myDTO",
            "field": "productId",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='myDTO'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/mycontroller"
}
```

How can I specify that I need only the error description messages or something like this?
Is there a smart/slim structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own custom exception and add Exception handler,

```
class ExceptionResponse {
    private boolean success = false;
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String exception;
    private List<String> errors;
    private String path;
    private String timestamp = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
}
```

Exception handler,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> invalidInput(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ExceptionResponse response = getExceptionResponse(); //generate exception response

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(response);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

These attributes are available at [`DefaultErrorAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html#getErrorAttributes-org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest-boolean-) as a `Map<String, Object>`.

> Default implementation of [ErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/ErrorAttributes.html). Provides the following attributes when possible: ...

If you want to modify `errors` you have to first get the map with the attributes and then modify and finally return it. Attributes are get using the [`DefaultErrorAttributes::getErrorAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html#getErrorAttributes-org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest-boolean-) method. The removal from the map is fairly simple with [`Map::remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove-java.lang.Object-).

Here is the code that should work. The returned bean should be [`ErrorAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/ErrorAttributes.html).

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, boolean includeStackTrace) {
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);
            errorAttributes.remove("errors");
            return errorAttributes;
        }
    };
}
```